# Random variable $X$ is symmetric iff $\mathbb{E}\left(X / \left(1 + r^2X^2\right)\right) = 0$ for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Can you prove/disprove the following claim?

Let $X$ be a random variable, which takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\mathbb{E}\left(X / \left(1 + r^2X^2\right)\right)$ is defined and finite for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$. The density of $X$ is symmetric about $0$ iff $$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{1 + r^2X^2}\right) = 0$$ for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

A couple of observations:

1. If $X$ is symmetric about $0$ then the expectation is $0$ for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$ because $x/(1+r^2x^2)$ is an odd function.
2. If the expectation condition was instead that $\mathbb{E}(g(X)) = 0$ for any odd function $g$ then it would be clear that $X$ must be symmetric, since we could just choose functions of the form
   $$g_s(x) = \begin{cases}
   -1 & \text{if } x \in (-s - \epsilon, -s),\\
   1 & \text{if } x \in (s, s + \epsilon),\\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$
   for any $s > 0$ and arbitrarily small $\epsilon$'s and just check that the density of $X$ is symmetric.

---

Context: I was watching a conference talk about e-values [(more info about e-values here)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.07801.pdf) and the speaker claimed (unless I misunderstood) that the following hypotheses are equivalent:
$$X \textrm{ is symmetric},$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}\left(1 + \frac{rX}{1 + r^2X^2}\right) \leq 1$$
for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$. The speaker said that the claim can be shown but I couldn't find the proof in any of his citations.

Comment: Just a remark, if $X$ is summetric (i.e. if the distribution of $X$ and of $-X$ is the same), then $X/(1+r^2 X^2)$ has the same distribution as its negative, hence the expected value has to be zero. This does not require densities (which is what you are using with the argument of the off function).

Comment: Another remark, $Y = X/(1 + r^2 X^2)$ _always_ has finite expectation since when $|X| \leq 1,$ then clearly $|Y| \leq 1$ and when $|X| > 1,$ then $|Y| \leq 1/(r^2 |X|) \leq 1/r^2.$ Thus, $|Y| \leq 1 + \frac{1}{r^2}$ is a bounded r.v.

Comment: Up-voted as an intriguing problem. A bit of poking shows that if $\int_0^\infty x(1 + r^2x^2)^{-1}g(x)\, dx = 0$ for all $r$ allows you to conclude $g=0$, you're done, but I haven't found that yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing $\beta=1/r^2$, the hypothesis amounts to
$$
0=E\left({X\over \beta+X^2}\right),\qquad\forall \beta>0.
$$
But $1/(\beta+X^2)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t(\beta+X^2)} dt$,
and so we  have (by Fubini)
$$
0=\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t} E\left[Xe^{-tX^2}\right] dt,\qquad\forall \beta>0.
$$
The function $t\mapsto E[X\exp(-tX^2)]$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ (dominated convergence), so by Laplace inversion,
$$
E[Xe^{-tX^2}]=0,\qquad\forall t>0.\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
By Stone-Weierstrass
$$
0=E[Xg(X^2)e^{-tX^2}],\qquad\forall t>0,
$$
for each continuous $g:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) =0$.
In particular, for each continuous $g$ of compact support, upon letting $t\downarrow 0$ we see that
$$
0=E[Xg(X^2)].
$$
Consequently, for each $C^1$  *odd* function $h$ of compact support
$$
0=E[h(X)],
$$
which means that $-X$ has the same distribution as $X$.
(And if $X$ has a density, the it's symmetric about $0$.)

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on how you apply Stone–Weierstrass?

Comment: @triple_sec: Fix $t>0$. Let $\mathcal A$ be the algebra of $C_0[0,\infty)$ functions such that $E[Xg(X^2)e^{-tX^2}]=0$. By equation (1) (written with $t+s$ instead of $t$), $\mathcal A$ contains all functions of the form $x\mapsto e^{-sx^2}$ for  $s>0$. Each of these functions is strictly positive, and if $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $[0,\infty)$ then $e^{-sx^2}\not=e^{-sy^2}$ (so $\mathcal A$ separates points). By the locally compact from of S-W, $\mathcal A$ is dense in $C_0[0,\infty)$ with respect to the uniform norm.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I guess the part that is still not immediately obvious to me is why $\mathcal A$ is a subalgebra of $C_0[0,\infty)$. That is, why it is the case that if $E[Xe^{-tX^2}g(X^2)]=0$ and $E[Xe^{-tX^2}h(X^2)]=0$ for all $t>0$, then $E[Xe^{-tX^2}g(X^2)h(X^2)]=0$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Good point (!), and I seem to have misstated things.  Better to take $\mathcal A$ to be the algebra generated by functions of the form $x\mapsto e^{-sx^2}$, $s>0$. As the product of two such exponentials is again a function of the same type, $\mathcal A$ could also be described as the vector space generated by the $e^{-sx^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I spent some time thinking about the problem myself, but didn’t get far. I could show by Fubini that $\mathbb E[\arctan(r X)]=0$ for all $r>0$, which yields in the limit as $r\to\infty$ (dominated convergence) that the distribution of $X$ places equal weights on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$. This is something, but one would also need that $(x,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-x)$ get assigned equal weights for any $x>0$. My hunch was that a full proof of symmetry would need some kind of approximation argument, and Stone–Weierstrass does look promising.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be okay to assume that $r^nE[|X|^n] \to 0$ for some $r>0$, i.e. the moments of $X$ do not grow faster than geometrically? If so, here would be a proof. In particular the mgf of $X$ exists for all $t$ small enough. It's moment generating function $t \mapsto E[e^{tX}] = \sum_n \frac{t^n}{n!}E[X^n]$  is determined by the moments of $X$. Same goes for $-X$ which has mgf  $t \mapsto E[e^{t(-X)}] = E[e^{-tX}] =\sum_n \frac{(-t)^n}{n!}E[X^n]$. Thus in this case to show that $X$ is symmetric, it suffices to show that all its odd moments are zero, since that would imply $X$ and $-X$ have the same mgf and hence the same distribution.

Now let's show your assumption implies all odd moments are zero. Note that by Taylor series $$\frac{rx}{1+(rx)^2} = rx - (rx)^3 + (rx)^5 - \cdots,$$ which is valid for all values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Plugging in $X$, taking expectations and using your assumption gives that
$$
E[rX - (rX)^3 + (rX)^5 - \cdots] = 0
$$
for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$.
Since $r_0^nE[|X|^n] \to 0$ for some $r_0>0$ small enough (our initial assumption), we have for $|r| < r_0$
$$
0 = E[rX - (rX)^3 + (rX)^5 - \cdots] = r E[X] - r^3 E[X^3] + r^5 E[X^5] - \cdots.
$$
The right hand side is a convergent power series in $r$ for $|r|<r_0$ that is identically zero, and hence its coefficients are all zero, giving that $E[X^n] = 0$ for all odd $n$, completing the proof.